# Split string on capital letters, but not if preceded by whitespace

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a string that looks like

> "AaaBbbCcc DddEee"

I'm splitting it with

```
my_string.scan(/[A-Z][a-z]+/)
```

and the result is

> ["Aaa", "Bbb", "Ccc", "Ddd", "Eee"]

What I'd like to achieve is to not split the string if the capital letter is preceded by a white space, so the result would look like

> ["Aaa", "Bbb", "Ccc Ddd", "Eee"]

Comment: You can also try to `split` at non-word boundary: [`\B(?=[A-Z])`](https://www.regex101.com/r/yzEZch/1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my_string.split(/(?<!\s)(?=[A-Z])/)
```

This matches positions that are not preceded by a whitespace (negative lookbehind - `(?<!\s)`) and are followed by a capital letter (positive lookahead - `(?=[A-Z])`).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to split or if the number of spaces in between the desired matches can be different, you may use your own approach and match additionally zero or more sequences of whitespace(s) + `[A-Z][a-z]+` by adding `(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)*` subpattern:

```
my_string.scan(/[A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)*/)
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/pBV91I)

To shorten it a bit, you may build the regex dynamically (see [demo here](https://ideone.com/GN6yOc)):

```
my_string = 'AaaBbbCcc DddEee'
block = "[A-Z][a-z]+"
puts my_string.scan(/#{block}(?:\s+#{block})*/)
```

And here is a Unicode-friendly version of the above regex ([online demo](https://ideone.com/7laXaO)):

```
my_string.scan(/\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+(?:\s+\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)*/)
```

where `\p{Lu}` matches any uppercase letter and `\p{Ll}` matches any lowercase letter.